# Anywhere but Here feat. Cryptics

Tags: knowledge, cryptic-clues, music

We are seven as told by an Englishman.
In his honor, enjoy these cryptic clues.

1. Fighting incessant blemish (3)
2. Misheard part begets silence (5)
3. Fleet courier triumph over headless elderly and chaos at mixed green (6, 9)
4. Westward farm surrounded by cheer and mirth (7)
5. Advancing years ruin a lodge (3, 3)
6. Wizard musician leaves us behind to gain silver. (8)
7. My wand falls short of the arcane. (6)

Who is the Englishman?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

1. > `WAR(-t)`
2. > `PEACE ("piece")`
3. > `WIN + (-a)GED + MESS + ENGER*`
4. > `JO(LLIT<)Y`
5. > `OLD AGE*`
6. > `M(-us)(AG)ICIAN`
7. > `MY + STIC(-k)`

> These are the names of the seven movements of [*The Planets*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Planets), an orchestral suite by English composer **Gustav Holst**.

Comment: you're too quick for me :)

Comment: How is farm=till? Till is a verb. Farm refers to the place where it is carried out.

Comment: @Sid: "Farm" can also be a verb.